# Determining if two ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ are equal

Tags: polynomials, ideals, polynomial-rings

I'm looking through old algebra exercises and came across this:

In $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ let $$G=(X-1,Y), H=(XY+X-1,2X-Y-2)$$ and
$$I= \langle G\rangle,  J=\langle H \rangle $$

I want to determine if $I=J$. My first guess is that they are not equal, since I think  $Y\notin J$ but $Y\in I$. But I'm not sure how to show this rigorously.
In a previous subproblem I have shown that $G$ is a Gröbner basis for $I$ but $H$ is not a Gröbner basis for $J$, so maybe I'm supposed to use this.
Edit: The Gröbner bases are w.r.t the lexicographic ordering

Comment: $G$ and $H$ are already ideals. What is the significance of using $\langle-\rangle$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Maybe $G$ and $H$ are *tuples* and then $I,J$ are their spans?

Comment: Yes, exactly @StinkingBishop. This is the notation used in the exercise

Comment: Hint: show that $J \subset \langle X-1/2,Y+3\rangle$.

Comment: @Mindlack $J\subset\langle X\color{red}{+}\frac{1}{2}, Y+3\rangle$.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop: oops, you’re right. Sorry for the stupid mistake.

Comment: @Mindlack Hmm, this isn't obvious to me. I would have to find polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ such that $f(XY+X-1)+g(2X-Y-2)=X+\frac{1}{2}$ and similarily with $Y+3$, right?

Comment: No, it’s the other way around, ie find polynomials $a,b$ such that $a(x,y) \cdot (x+1/2)+b(x,y)\cdot (y+3)=xy+x-1$ and same for $2x-y-2$.

Comment: @Mindlack Could you provide me with another hint? Is there a clever way of finding these polynomials other than you looking at it until you get an epiphany?
And when you then have this inclusion, I imagine you want to show that $I$ is not contained in $\langle X+1/2, Y+3 \rangle$ meaning it can't be contained in $J$ so they can't be equal?

Comment: @Snildt: you won’t usually (in this kind of situations) find explicit $a,b$, but rather prove that they exist, typically by showing that the images of $xy+x-1$ and $2x-y-2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x+1/2,y+3\rangle$ vanish. You certainly won’t find them by just “looking at them”, although you can try and solve a linear system by taking low-degree $a,b$. The next part of the proof is as you suggested. Mario G’s answer is the one closest to the line of argument I’m suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that $\{XY+X-1,2X-Y-2\}$ is not a Gröbner basis with respect to the lex order (I'll assume that $Y>X$, as mentioned in the comments).
In this case, the leading term of $XY+X-1$ is $YX$ and the leading term of your linear form is $-Y$, so replace it by $Y+2-2X$.

Reducing $XY+X-1$ with respect to $Y\leadsto 2X-2$ gives you $X(2X-2)+X-1 = 2X^2-X-1$, which in particular explains the result in the other answer. You now have the ideal

$$J = (2X^2-X-1,Y-2X+2)$$

and since there is no overlapping between the leading terms, you know that this is a Gröbner basis. In particular, since $Y=2X-2$ in the quotient, you see that $J$ defines the finite dimensional algebra

$$ \mathbb Q[X]/(2X^2-X-1)
$$
and this is generated by $1$ and $X$ over $\mathbb Q$: it is of dimension two.

On the other hand, the ideal $I$ has as quotient $\mathbb Q$ as $Y=0$ and $X=1$, so that the dimension is $1$. Hence, your two ideals cannot be equal, as they define algebras of different dimensions.

Comment: I'm not too well-versed in Gröbner bases, what exactly does it mean to "reduce $XY+X-1$ with respect to $Y$ squiggly arrow $2X-2$? 
The last part is not quite clear to me either. How does $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(2X^2-X-1)$ relate to the problem?

Comment: @Snildt In my answer I explain that: the quotient by $J$ is isomorphic to that algebra. Reduce means "replace $Y$ by that expression."

Comment: Oh I get it now, that's very clever! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f\colon \Bbb Q[X,Y]\to \Bbb Q[T]$ given by $X\mapsto T$, $Y\mapsto 2T-2$. Observe that $f$ maps $X-1$, $Y$ to $T-1$, $2(T-1)$ whereas it maps $XY+X-1$, $2X-Y-2$ map to $2T^2-T-1$, $0$. The ideals generated in $\Bbb Q[T]$ clearly differ.

Comment: I have not seen this type of argument before - transforming ideals in two variables to ideals in one variable. Is there anything special about this $f$ you defined, or can this be done with arbitrary transformations? And will it always behave nicely? I mean will ideals that are equal always be mapped to the same ideal even if pick different generators?

Comment: @Snildt Maybe my answer clarifies what is happening here: Hagen is eliminating $Y$ from the picture, and noticing that his map $f$ defines isomorphisms of the resulting quotients with a one-generated polynomial algebra (which ends up being finite dimensional).

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $Y \in J$, then there would exist polynomials $P(X,Y),Q(X,Y) \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ such that $$Y = P(X,Y) \cdot (XY+X-1)+Q(X,Y)(2X-Y-2).$$

Let's find a contradiction with this equality. Consider the system formed by the equations $XY+X-1=0$ and $2X-Y-2=0$. Its solutions are $(x,y) = (1,0)$ and $(x,y) = (-1/2,-3)$. The previous polynomial equation must be satisfied for each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$. In particular, if we take $(x,y) = (-1/2,-3)$, we obtain $-3=0$, which is obviously false in $\mathbb{Q}$.